# How can I tell whether a Scala macro's param is a function?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I'm trying to write a macro that operates on a function parameter. I handled anonymous functions of all argument lengths pretty easily by making the parameter to the macro `Any` and then matching on `Function(body, params)`, but I'd like to be able to pass in a reference to a function variable:

```
val valFunction = (something: Int) => (something * 3).toString
val functionVal = Macros.myMacro(valFunction)
```

I was able to use `WeakTypeTag`s as per the [official documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) to make this work with a function of one parameter:

```
def myMacro[T, U](param: T => U) = macro myMacroImpl[T, U]

def myMacroImpl[T, U](c: Context)(param: c.Expr[T => U])
     (implicit tt: c.WeakTypeTag[T], implicit ut: c.WeakTypeTag[T]) = {...}
```

but then the macro only works for functions of one parameter. I tried checking for a member named "apply" that was also a method, but I ran into erasure issues and also was concerned about overloaded methods and the such. The workaround I'm currently cringing my way through is to create 23 macros for `Function0` through `Function22`, but whoo-boy I'm not happy about it. Is there another approach I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach to solve this problem is to create a simple type class that would be only available for functions:

```
trait Functionable[T]
```

With implicit macro that materializes implicit values:

```
object Functionable {
  implicit def materialize[T]: Functionable[T] = macro materialize_impl[T]
  def materialize_impl[T](c: Context)(implicit ttag: c.WeakTypeTag[T]): c.Expr[Functionable[T]] = {
    val funcs = (0 to 22).map { c.universe.definitions.FunctionClass(_) }.toList
    if (funcs.exists { ttag.tpe.typeSymbol == _ })
      c.universe.reify { new Functionable[T] { } }
    else {
      c.abort(c.macroApplication.pos, "not a function")
    }
  }
}
```

This particular implementation won't work for subtypes but you can customize it if you need more.

And then we can define a macro as:

```
def myMacro[T](f: T)(implicit functionable: Functionable[T]) = macro myMacroImpl[T]
def myMacroImpl[T](c: Ctx)(f: c.Expr[T])(functionable: c.Expr[Functionable[T]])(implicit ttag: c.WeakTypeTag[T]): c.Expr[String] = c.literal(ttag.tpe.toString)
```

This macro will only be expanded for functions and will fail with compile-time implicit not found error if argument is not a function. From withing a macro you can reflectively get the info about types through weak type tag of the function type.

[Whole example can be found here](https://gist.github.com/densh/7769594).

Comment: `c.universe.definitions.FunctionClass` was exactly what I was looking for! The implicit typeclass is interesting but I went with just matching on the type tag using FunctionClass and aborting the macro in case of a nonmatch. Thanks!

Comment: Some minor enhancements: 1) by the virtue of @implicitNotFound you can provide the users with a custom compilation error message, 2) i would probably make Functionable a class so that you don't have to create a new anonymous subclass every time materialization happens

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to accept `Any` (or unbound generic) as your macro parameter type and then manually check inside your macro that the argument is actually one of `Function0` to `Function22`. This doesn't have to be that tedious, though:

```
val functionTypes = for(i <- 0 to 22) 
  yield c.mirror.staticClass(s"scala.Function$i").toType.erasure
```

Now, is my `Tree`'s type one of the above?

```
functionTypes.exists(funTpe => tree.tpe <:< funTpe)
```